# Dockerfile or image for running ROS noetic with nvidia gpu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, nvidia, ros

I have been trying to build a docker container in Ubuntu-22.04 using the following Dockerfile (modified from https://github.com/sunsided/ros-gazebo-gpu-docker.git)

```
FROM nvidia/cudagl:11.4.2-base-ubuntu20.04

ENV TZ=Asia/Kolkata \
    DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
    
# Run a full upgrade and install utilities for development.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get install -y \
    mesa-utils \
    vim \
    nano \
    build-essential gdb \
    cmake cmake-curses-gui \
    git \
    ssh \
    curl \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Register the ROS package sources.
ENV UBUNTU_RELEASE=focal
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $UBUNTU_RELEASE main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
RUN wget --output-document - \
  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | apt-key add -

# Install ROS.
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    ros-noetic-desktop-full \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    python3-rosdep python3-rosinstall python3-rosinstall-generator python3-wstool build-essential\
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Initialize rosdep
RUN rosdep init

# Only for nvidia-docker 1.0
LABEL com.nvidia.volumes.needed="nvidia_driver"
# ENV PATH /usr/local/nvidia/bin:${PATH}
# ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/nvidia/lib:/usr/local/nvidia/lib64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# nvidia-container-runtime (nvidia-docker2)
ENV NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES \
   ${NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES:-all}
ENV NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES \
   ${NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES:+$NVIDIA_DRIVER_CAPABILITIES,}graphics

# Some QT-Apps/Gazebo don't show controls without this
ENV QT_X11_NO_MITSHM 1

# Create users and groups.
ARG ROS_USER_ID=1000
ARG ROS_GROUP_ID=1000

RUN addgroup --gid $ROS_GROUP_ID ros \
 && useradd --gid $ROS_GROUP_ID --uid $ROS_USER_ID -ms /bin/bash -p "$(openssl passwd -1 ros)" -G root,sudo ros \
 && echo '%sudo ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL' >> /etc/sudoers 

# Source the ROS configuration.
RUN echo "source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash" >> /home/ros/.bashrc


USER ros
RUN rosdep update
WORKDIR /home/${USER}
```

The Dockerfile is inside a docker folder in the home directory and is run using

```
docker build ~/Docker -t  ros_noetic
```

Then the following noetic_image.bash file is used to run the docker container from the home directory

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# See http://wiki.ros.org/docker/Tutorials/Hardware%20Acceleration

set -euo pipefail

# See README.md for building this image.
CONTAINER_NAME=ros
DOCKER_IMAGE=ros_noetic

# Which GPUs to use; see https://github.com/NVIDIA/nvidia-docker
GPUS="all"

XSOCK=/tmp/.X11-unix

XAUTH=`pwd`/.tmp/docker.xauth
XAUTH_DOCKER=/tmp/.docker.xauth

if [ ! -f $XAUTH ]
then
    xauth_list=$(xauth nlist :0 | sed -e 's/^..../ffff/')
    if [ ! -z "$xauth_list" ]
    then
        echo "$xauth_list" | xauth -f $XAUTH nmerge -
    else
        touch $XAUTH
    fi
    chmod a+r $XAUTH
fi

docker run --rm -it \
    --name "$CONTAINER_NAME" \
    --gpus "$GPUS" \
    --env="DISPLAY" \
    --env="QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1" \
    --env="XAUTHORITY=$XAUTH_DOCKER" \
    --volume="$XSOCK:$XSOCK:rw" \
    --volume="$XAUTH:$XAUTH_DOCKER:rw" \
    $DOCKER_IMAGE \
    bash
```

On running the bash file the following error pops up

```
$ ./noetic_image.bash 
xauth:  error in locking authority file /home/<user>/.tmp/docker.xauth
```

Where are we supposed to find the .tmp folder? Although this can be run without including the xauth, on running gazebo libgl error pops up.

Could anyone help me with modifying the Dockerfile or bash file or suggest any other better method. I would like to use docker to run ros noetic with gpu and opengl support for gazebo projects. Note that I have already installed the official NVIDIA Container Toolkit from https://docs.nvidia.com/datacenter/cloud-native/container-toolkit/latest/install-guide.html

```
$ docker run -it --rm --gpus all ubuntu nvidia-smi
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/ubuntu
bccd10f490ab: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:77906da86b60585ce12215807090eb327e7386c8fafb5402369e421f44eff17e
Status: Downloaded newer image for ubuntu:latest
Tue Mar 12 14:44:29 2024       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 550.54.14              Driver Version: 550.54.14      CUDA Version: 12.4     |
|-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id          Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |           Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                        |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+========================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650        Off |   00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   51C    P0             15W /   50W |       5MiB /   4096MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                        |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
                                                                                         
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                              |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                              GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                               Usage      |
|=========================================================================================|
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Thank you for any help (well in advanced)!

Comment: Not the best option but if you run `xhost +`  on your host before starting the docker container, then you should be able to do without all the `XAUTH` stuff. DISPLAY and XSOCK should then be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the comment I will try it out. Where is the .tmp supposed to be in Ubuntu? And why is xhost required for running gpu? nvidia-smi and gazebo still works except there is some error libgl which pops up but doesn't necessarily hinder the application.